# Alinear div con color a la derecha y alinear los elementos dentro de él

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap

intento poner mi recuadro color negro con transparencia  al lado derecho, que el texto abarque todo el recuadro de color y bajar mi texto pero no me está quedando.
Esto trabajando con un slider.

> Este es mi código.

```css
.carousel-caption {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(44, 62, 80, .7), rgba(44, 62, 80, .7));
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right!important;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-item active">
            <img alt="Los Angeles" height="auto" src="<?=base_url()?>images/carousel/centro_sur4.jpg" width="100%">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-10 offset-md-6 offset-sm-2 offset-1 text-carousel text-center">
                        <h3>
                            ¡Bienvenido a Querétaro!
                        </h3>
                        <p>
                            Muchas empresas nacionales  y extranjeras  se instalan en Querétaro cada mes y  en Abacom sabemos lo importante que es arrancar sin contratiempos.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Permita a Abacom ser su aliado tecnológico y apoye con expertos en conectividad de su empresa. Conozca como hemos ayudado a otras empresas en sus inicios
                            <a class="dark-blue" href="<?=base_url()?>index.php/abacom/testimoniales">
                                <mark>
                                    aquí
                                </mark>
                            </a>
                            e imagine lo que podemos hacer por usted.
                        </p>
                        <a class="btn btn-transparent-white btn-medium border-radius-4" href="" target="_blank">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus">
                            </i>
                            Ver más
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </img>
        </div>
```

> Este es mi resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Lo que quiero hacer es recorrer el recuadro de color gris hacia donde esta la marca color rojo y centrar el texto que esta dentro del recuadro color gris como se muestra en el ejemplo color rojo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías explicar un poco mejor? No entiendo lo que necesitas... Algún ejemplo de lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: ya anexe una imagen como ejemplo

Comment: Estas usando bootstrap? porque no lo manejas con las columnas ?

Comment: si utilizo bootstrap, y si me muestras un ejemplo?

Comment: Hola, si estás con bootstrap te recomiendo usar flex para estas cosas, te dejo link a la documentacion. [Documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/). Hay varias formas de ordenar los elementos pero acorde a tu imagen creo que la clase que tienes que ocupar es **class="d-flex justify-content-between"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una de las mejores formas de alinear elementos en `CSS` es usar las propiedades de `flexbox` (Cajas flexibles), fácilmente puedes organizar su `layout` con base a sus necesidades.

Le dejo un ejemplo sencillo de cómo puedes alinear elementos en los ejes con `flexbox`.

`Display: flex:` Le permite acomodar elementos uno al lado del otro.

`Justify-content:` Permite acomodar los elementos en el eje horizontal.

`Align – ítems:` acomoda los elementos  en el eje vertical.

Lo invito a que consultes un poco más sobre `Flexbox` y sus propiedades, o bien puede buscar en la documentación de Bootstrap el uso de las etiquetas indicadas para centrar elementos o usar esta forma que le expongo.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  background: url("https://stackoverflow.blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/SO_Teams.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container .content {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.container .content .card {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.container .content .card h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container .content .card p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container .content .card .btn {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  line-height: 2;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}

.container .content .card .btn:hover {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
}

.container .content .card .btn:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.95);
  transform: scale(0.95);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>Ejemplo para Stackoverflow</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/Estilos.css">
</head>

<body>
    <section class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="title">
                    <h1>Lorem, ipsum.</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse quas perferendis ut quis? Veniam
                        id,
                        impedit aliquam maiores possimus minima similique laudantium quia voluptatem non reprehenderit.
                        Placeat sapiente architecto alias!</p>
                </div>
                <button class="btn">Ver Más</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```